# Preferred Mac OS X installer

Tags: macos, installation

I need your help in choosing a Mac OS X installer version for my application, since I'm not a native Mac user (I am a Windows user). 
As far as I know there are two popular installer versions: the regular setup wizard, and the one that uses a window in which you drag the file into the applications folder. Which is preferred and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is entirely self contained with all its resources bundled in a single `.app` package (which is the preferred structure for Mac applications) then use drag and drop installation.  If it isn't possible to bundle your application in this way then use an installer `.pkg`.

There may be other solutions that are appropriate for certain types of application.  For example I develop a large Java application that runs on many platforms (including Mac) and we use [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) to build one installer JAR that works on all platforms.  We then package this up as an .exe for Windows users (using [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)) and as a .app bundle for Mac users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you also please let me know the preferred installation regardless of technical issues, but a mac native user?

Comment: The preferred approach is a drag and drop `.app` bundle if it is possible for your app to work like that. That way everything is self-contained and uninstallation simply requires deleting the app. If your app cannot be bundled as a single `.app` then a `.pkg` is the next best option (installed with the native `Installer.app`). In either case distributed as a `.dmg` disk image, or failing that a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with command line tools or simply not inclined, I would recommend two different IDEs:

- Packages - a free and great way to create OSX Installer packages. It is simple to use out of the box, but has great depth for conditional installs.
   http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html
- DMGPackager - shareware - a simple app to create DMG with optional backgrounds, licenses etc. 
   http://www.skoobysoft.com/utilities/dmgp.html

If you want to distribute, it would be best to sign the installer.